# сигнал sigpipe при подключении к серверу

Tags: c, сеть

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main () {
    struct sockaddr_in serv, cli;
    int sock;
    socklen_t clen;
    const char* msg = "message";    

    serv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port = htons(13);
    serv.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) <0) 
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Не удается создать сокет: %s", strerror(errno));

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv, sizeof(serv)) < 0)
         errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Не удается подготовить сокет: %s", strerror(errno));
    if (listen(sock, 20) < 0) 
        errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Не удается подготовить сокет: %s", strerror(errno));

    for (;;) {
        if (accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli, &clen) < 0)
                warn("Не удается принять соединение: %s", strerror(errno));
        send(sock, msg, sizeof msg, 0);
    }
    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
```

почему  он посылается, как побороть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посылается он (signаl SIGPIPE), когда вы пытаетесь писать в socket, который уже никто не читает. Об этом написано в [man 2 write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write)

> ```
>   EPIPE  fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed.  When this happens
>           the  writing  process  will also receive a SIGPIPE signal.  (Thus, the write return
>           value is seen only if the program catches, blocks or ignores this signal.)
> ```

Самый постой способ побороть -- игнорировать этот сигнал, написав где-то в начале программы

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Конкретно в вашем коде такое поведение возникает из-за того, что вы пишете **не в тот сокет**. Писать надо в сокет, который возвращает `accept()`,  не в тот, что вы слушаете и передаете в `accept` первым параметром.

Данная часть кода должна выглядеть как-то так

```
for (;;) {
    int new_s = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli, &clen);
    if (new_s < 0)
        warn("Не удается принять соединение: %s", strerror(errno));
    else {
        send(new_s, msg, sizeof msg, 0);
        close(new_s);
    }
}
```

Comment: я с помощью телнета подключаюсь.
почему никто не читает?

Comment: Потому, что просто пишете код (без толкового проясняющего ситуацию текста)  и с чего-то решили, что его будут **изучать**. Вообще-то, `accept` возвращает сокет, вот в него (а не в тот, что вы передаете в `accept()` и надо писать).